# How to build react native project to aar library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aar

Is it possible to build a RN project to an AAR package that can be integrated by other Android apps? And is there any similar solution for iOS?

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to [this github repo](https://github.com/glung/react-native-as-an-android-lib). It has two projects lib and application. "lib" is a RN project which can be build to generate the aar and then import it into "application" project which is an Android project (but it could also be another RN project)